# void pointers into a string not outputting properly in C

Tags: c, void-pointers

Consider this code:

```
void foo(void* obj) {
    NodePtr node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    char* word = (char*)obj;

    node->data= malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(word)+1));
    *((char*)(node->data)) = *(word); //assumed to be the problem

    printf(": %s\n", (node->data));
    printf(": %s\n", word);
}
```

What I basically want to do is set a void pointer attribute (**data**) of a **node** struct to a string value.

For some reason, the first print comes out as garbage, while the second print works out fine.
I assume something is wrong with attempting to set the value of my node's **data** attribute to the value of **word**, the line indicated by the comment.  I tried to typecast **word** into a char pointer, but that did not help.  I tried to replace **(word)** with a char* typecast of **obj** as well.

One thing that should be noted is that the "gibberish" is actually the first letter of what it's supposed to be (ex: if printing out **word** prints out apples, then the other print statement gives *a* the first time, then in later function calls, it would be something like *a^q*.

I printed **strlen(word)** to make sure I was allocating the right amount of space, and that seems to check out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

```
node->data= malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 );
strcpy( (char*)node->data, word );
```

instead of

```
node->data= malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(word)+1));
*((char*)(node->data)) = *(word);
```